# javascript crashes browsers

Tags: javascript, joomla2.5, webcam, setinterval

here's my situation : 
I have written a small javascript code to autorefresh images coming into my server from external source every 5 Seconds, on the same lines as we would refresh images for a webcam.This js needs to be used in website being made using Joomla.
**problem** The Javascript causes the broswers' FF and Chrome to crash after sometime. I'm attaching the code. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
    <body>
    <center>
     <h2>human cam</h2>
      <img id="pic" src="images/CB1.jpeg" border="0" width="500" height="500" /></center>
      <script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript">

      function refresh() 
     {         

     document.images["pic"].src = "images/CB1.jpeg" + "?" + new Date().getTime();

     setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 5000 );

     }
     window.onload=function(){
 refresh();
    }
    </script>
   </body>
```

//P.S moderators I've added joomla and webcam as tags because I have picked up the code from people who used it for webcam refresh, so would like their inputs; and Joomla as I need to further integrate this code Thanks

Comment: No need to concatenate "images/CB1.jpeg" and "?". Just use `"images/CB1.jpeg?" + new Date().getTime();`

Comment: @Ian thank you for the reply.Will see to it that I make appropriate changes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each call of `refresh()` you're creating a new timer which calls `refresh()` which creates a new timer which calls `refresh()` which creates a new timer...

Change it to

```
function refresh()
    document.images["pic"].src = "images/CB1.jpeg" + "?" + new Date().getTime();
}

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(refresh, 5000);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I didnt realise that mistake as I'm a newbie. Thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 1):

You have created recursion badly over here

```
function refresh() 
     {         

     document.images["pic"].src = "images/CB1.jpeg" + "?" + new Date().getTime();

     setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 5000 );

     }
```

your refresh function sets more intervals over and over endlessly

try this one

```
function refresh() 
     {         

     document.images["pic"].src = "images/CB1.jpeg" + "?" + new Date().getTime();



     }
     window.onload=function(){
 setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 5000 ); /// set interval onload just one time 
    }
```